# Nested query not working on Elasticsearch 1.7 if mapping with same name exists

Tags: elasticsearch

I just downgraded my local ES from 2.1.8 to 1.7.5 to match AWS Elasticsearch and now my nested queries aren't working. I have to admit I'm baffled and couldn't find anything helpful online.

I've abbreviated the following for clarity and changed some of the names but otherwise these are real outputs from my local ES. The final nested result correctly returned file documents with the matching package on 2.1 but nothing on 1.7.

**Update:** I actually have another nested field that is not exhibiting this problem. The difference is the value for that is a single nested object instead of an array. Known issue?

**Update #2:** Changing the value to a single value made no difference. However, changing the nested property name from `package` to `packages` made the problem go away. The only thing I can think of is that I also have a mapping called `package`, would that cause a problem?

### Mapping

```
"file": {
    "dynamic": "strict",
    "_all": {
      "enabled": false
    },
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "type": {
        "type": "string",
        "index": "not_analyzed"
      },
      "package": {
        "type": "nested",
        "dynamic": "strict",
        "properties": {
          "name": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          },
          "path": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          }            
      }
   }
}
```

### Document

Search

```
{ "query": {"term": {"type": "file"}} }
```

Result

```
{
    "_index": "blah",
    "_type": "file",
    "_id": "slkdfjsdfjsoijfoisjfisdjf",
    "_score": 7.8872123,
    "_source": {
      "name": "foo",
      "type": "file",
      "package": [
        {
          "name": "the_package",
          "path": "the_package!path"
        }
      ]
    }
 }
```

### Term Vectors

```
localhost:9200/blah/file/slkdfjsdfjsoijfoisjfisdjf/_termvector?pretty=true&fields=package.name

{
  "_index": "blah",
  "_type": "file",
  "_id": "slkdfjsdfjsoijfoisjfisdjf",
  "_version": 1,
  "found": true,
  "took": 1,
  "term_vectors": {
    "package.name": {
      "field_statistics": {
        "sum_doc_freq": 1040,
        "doc_count": 1040,
        "sum_ttf": 1040
      },
      "terms": {
        "the_package": {
          "term_freq": 1,
          "tokens": [
            {
              "position": 0,
              "start_offset": 0,
              "end_offset": 7
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Nested Query

```
{
    "query": {
        "nested":{
            "path": "package",
            "query": {
                "term": {
                    "package.name": "the_package"
                }
            }
        }
    }           
}
```

Result

```
{
  "took": 8,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 10,
    "successful": 10,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 0,
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": []
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following update #2 I tried deleting the `package` mapping and sure enough the nested query now works as expected. I'll update my mappings to avoid this issue.

Nothing in the ES nested object documentation suggests this should be an issue and it has obviously been fixed between 1.7.5 and 2.1.8 so if anyone knows of such documentation or a link to a fixed bug feel free to add. Posting this as an answer in case anyone else hits this.